# How can I set a default value for "ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" into a ResourceDictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2022, resourcedictionary, .net-4.8

I want to set a default value for `ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay` into a `ResourceDictionary`...

My element:

```xml
<Border x:Name="VersionBox_Border"
        Grid.Column="0"
        ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="500">
    <Border.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Content="..."/>
    </Border.ToolTip>
</Border>
```

My ResourceDictionary:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <system:Double x:Key="Common_ToolTip_msTime">500</system:Double>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I am trying something like this:

```xml
<Border x:Name="VersionBox_Border"
        Grid.Column="0"
        ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="{DynamicResource Common_ToolTip_msTime}">
    <Border.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Content="..."/>
    </Border.ToolTip>
</Border>
```

And I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: ''500' is not a valid value for property 'InitialShowDelay'.'
```

Comment: Why `system:Double` when the property type is `int`?

Comment: @Clemens I have tried with `int` too `<system:Int16 x:Key="Common_ToolTip_msTime">500</system:Int16>` but I get the same error...

Comment: int is Int32...

Comment: Oh god... Yes, you are right! I am inexcusable... My brain is boiled. Thank you very much and sorry for this silly question!

Comment: δεν πειράζει...

Comment: Hahahaha... :-)